# react-native-photo-editor - no crop option

Tags: react-native

I've just added react-native-photo-editor and everything is working perfectly apart from cropping. There is no option for this. I've tested on 3 different Android devices & the simulator but all are the same.

```
RNPhotoEditor.Edit({
  path: response.path,
  hiddenControls: ['save'],
  onCancel: () => { Actions.pop() },
  onDone: () => { Actions.refresh({ key: Math.random() }) }
});
```

I've read through the documentation but looks as though this should be shown as default since its not in my 'hiddenControls' array.

You can see in the first image there is no crop option but in the second image taken from the documentation you can see it is there.

Thanks in advance.

[image: image editor without crop option]

[image: image editor with crop option]

Comment: because there is no crop feature in the native Android library that react-native-photo-editor relies on

Comment: Thank you. I am now using another package to crop and then this to draw over.